# Why is my table's encoding wrong?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, utf-8, utf8mb4

I'm using Rails 5 and MySQL 5.7. I have the following in my database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  pool: 5
  encoding: utf8mb4
  charset: utf8mb4
  collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: [...]
  username: [...]
  password: [...]
```

I run `rake db:reset` to recreate my database and I run `show create table users` and I see `CREATE TABLE`users`([...]) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`.

Why does my `CHARSET=utf8` and how can I fix it (make it equal `utf8mb4`)? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rake db:reset` is wrong. `rake db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:migrate` is correct.

The `reset` just created the tables from the already stored schema which had the wrong charset and collation. But re-creating them from the migrations created them with the new charset and collation.

Answer (score 1):

Be explicit when you create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
        name VARCHAR(99)  NOT NULL,
        ...
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

Another technique is to ignore the table default, and be explicit on each column:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
        name VARCHAR(99)  CHARACTER SET utf8mb4  NOT NULL,
        ...
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

*Probably* what happened is that you specified the charset in neither place, but the `DEFAULT` on the *database* was utf8.

Comment: Actually the default on the database is utf8mb4. `| character_set_database   | utf8mb4` But Rails is not respecting this. It's a Rails question as much as anything; I can be explicit every time but I don't want to.

Comment: Does Rails create the table for you?  (I don't know RoR.)

Comment: yup, it does create the table for you, if you use the usual workflow. See my answer below for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `db:reset` calls `db:schema:load`.  If your `db/schema.rb` file has bad encoding values, it will load up the bad stuff. You can fix your `db/schema.rb` to have correct encoding before running `db:reset`